# Why Function.prototype.bind.apply?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I understand how `Function.prototype.bind.apply` works. Suppose the following definitions:

```
var Constructor = function(someArgument){
    //constructor body here
};

var creator = function(ctor, args){
    args.unshift(null); //or anything else to make 'bind' succeed
    return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(ctor, args));
};

var creator2 = function(ctor, args){
    return new ctor(args);
};

var obj = creator(Constructor, ['someVar']);
var obj2 = creator2(Constructor, ['someVar']);
```

Both `creator` and `creator2` work, so why would one choose `creator` over `creator2`?

Comment: *apply* is just a convenient way to set the value of *this* when calling function so you can just pass *arguments* (for example) rather than having to build up a call expression containing each argument. I don't think there is anything to recommend it other than convenience. If there are zero or one parameters, then it doesn't have any benefit over *call*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `creator2` passes the `args` array as a single array parameter to the constructor.

Calling `creator` passes each item in the array as a separate parameter (via `apply`).

Comment: Not sure that explains *why* one should be chosen over the other.

Comment: Thanks, this was some (important) detail that I overlooked. This also explains why `return new (ctor.bind(null, args));` would not suit.

Comment: @RobG: They do two different things.  You should chose whichever one you need.

Comment: The OP started with "*I understand how Function.prototype.bind.apply works…*" so I naively assumed that s/he knew how it works.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase it as "_I think_ I understand how ... works".